# HTML Message Sender

Tags: javascript, html, email

I am trying to make a button that will allow me to send a preset message to an email address. I don't want it to be a form, or an email tab that sends the message. I just want to be able to click a button, so that I can send this premade message. Is there any way that I could do that?

Comment: You can't do that in just a client. You need a backend page (like php) that will send a message and Ajax that will triger that page.

Comment: You can't do it from the browser, but you could call a server-side script to do it. You'd need to hook up an Ajax call to your button to tell the server to send the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the exact answer you're look for, but an easy alternative would be:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@gmail.com?subject=Some%20Subject&body=Message%20Here">Send Message</a>
```

Make sure you replace spaces with %20

Answer (score 1):

You can add an <a> tag with a mailto: href:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=your subject&body=your message">
   Click here to email me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but you're going to need some sort of backend, like Python, .NET, Rails, or PHP. When you click the button, it would have to be either a link or a form submit button that sends a request to some backend page that handles actually sending the email.

Each backend has its own specific way of doing this. You would need to specify which language you wish to use for anyone to provide further help.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a serverside script to send the email. Your button could fire an AJAX request to the serverside script to send the email that way.

Unfortunately there is no way to send emails strictly using HTML or javascript (with Node being the exception).